# My rock, paper, scissor game does give no outputs after inputting my move. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I can't get the hang of what I'm doing wrong here. Whenever I run the code the program just stops after taking input. I don't understand why does it not proceed by entering the functions.

Any help will be appreciated

```
import random

def Main():
    g_options = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
    rand_choice = random.choice(g_options)
    print(rand_choice)
    per_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissor?").islower()
    # valid = False
    while per_choice == rand_choice:
        per_choice = input("Oh same answers. Let's do it again. Rock, paper, Scissor?").islower

    if per_choice == "paper":
        Paper_Choice(per_choice)
    elif per_choice == "rock":
        Rock_Choice(per_choice)
    elif per_choice == "scissor":
        Scissor_Choice(per_choice)

def Rock_Choice(X):
    if X == "scissor":  # This is if computers choice is rock
        return "you lose"
    elif X == "paper":
        return "you win"

def Paper_Choice (X):
    if X == "rock":  # This is if computers choice is paper
        return "you lose"
    elif X == "scissor":
        return "you win"

def Scissor_Choice(X):
    if X == "rock":  # This is if computers choice is scissor
        return "you win"
    elif X == "paper":
        return "you lose"

Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input variable ist set to the string.is_lower function -you do not call it so it does not even tests if the whole input is lower case or not:

> ```
> per_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissor?").islower
> ```

You probably ment to use

```
per_choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissor?").lower()
```

to make it lower case.

Your check methods only use `if: ... elif:...` no `else:` so you get no output at all.

```
# X is the "function_adress" of str.is_lower function
```

> ```
>    def Rock_Choice(X):
>         if X == "scissor":  # This is if computers choice is rock
>             return "you lose"
>         elif X == "paper":
>             return "you win"
>
>     def Paper_Choice (X):
>         if X == "rock":  # This is if computers choice is paper
>             return "you lose"
>         elif X == "scissor":
>             return "you win"
>
>     def Scissor_Choice(X):
>         if X == "rock":  # This is if computers choice is scissor
>             return "you win"
>         elif X == "paper":
>             return "you lose"
> ```

You could have easily debugged that using `print` statements to veryfy what `X` is inputted into your methods:

```
def Rock_Choice(X):
    print(X)
    if X == "scissor":  # This is if computers choice is rock
        return "you lose"
    elif X == "paper":
        return "you win"
```

or next to where you get the values:

```
while per_choice == rand_choice:
    per_choice = input("Oh same answers. Let's do it again. Rock, paper, Scissor?").islower
    print(per_choice)
```

etc.